# Stack paints Container, but not DecoratedBox

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I simply want to show a red box in a Stack with some other Widgets, but when I use DecoratedBox instead of Container, it doesn't paint on screen. I thought DecoratedBox was simply a more explicit version of Container, what am I missing?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        DecoratedBox( // doesn't work
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `Stack` doesn't render the `DecoratedBox` is that is doesn't have a default size. On the other hand, `Container` will its parent by default.

`Container` is not just a `DecoratedBox`. It also uses other widgets, including `SizedBox` and `Alignment`.

As such:

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
)
```

is not equivalent to:

```dart
DecoratedBox(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
)
```

but instead to:

```dart
SizedBox.expand(
  child: DecoratedBox(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't expect that I would get the answer this quick. I think I don't have a clear understanding of the usage of `DecoratedBox`. Should it be only used with parent Widget that specifies width and height? Why would I use `DecoratedBox` when I can specify `decoration` in `Container`? Apologies for the extra questions.

Comment: `Container` uses `DecoratedBox`. So it's not "one or another". In both cases, you are using `DecoratedBox`.